# Compression and distribution of structured data in postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, compression

I am creating a table which is very huge(in TB)  in postgresql db  and like greenplum I like to specify the compression size and distribute the data randomly
But in the postgresql documentation, I can't find any clause for compression

Any idea how can I achieve the compression and random distribution of the data in postgresql

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compression, there is only TOAST. That compresses data automatically, but only for large rows (exceeding 2000 bytes). There is no way to compress the whole table as such.

I am not sure what "random data distribution" in a table is, but if you want to distribute that table data across several devices, you have to define tablespaces for them and use hash partitioning with a partition on each tablespace.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, random distribution means, I don't want to distribute my data using primary or unique keys, there should be random distribution as the table size is very huge

Comment: Oh, ok. There is not much benefit to that, except to spread across several devices, as indicated in my answer. If you don't want that, there is no benefit in distributing data randomly. If anything, that would be a disadvantage, because caching becomes less effective.

Answer (score 1):

For compression, PostgreSQL will do this automatically for you when they go above a certain size. Compression is applied at each individual data value though - not at the full table level. Meaning that if you have a billion rows that are very narrow, they won't get compressed. Or if you have very many columns each with only a small value in it, they won't get compressed. Details about this scheme in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html).

If you need it on the full table level, a solution is to create a TABLESPACE for those tables that you want to be compressed and point it to a compressed filesystem. As long as the filesystem still obeys fsync() and standard POSIX semantics, this should be perfectly safe. Details about this in the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-tablespaces.html).

PostgreSQL is not natively distributed. If you want a distributed version of PostgreSQL where data can be spread across several nodes, and have those nodes use replication for high availability, there are some 3rd party options like:

- [Postgres-XL](https://www.postgres-xl.org/) - a forked version of Postgres designed to be distributed and has some other features like MPP.

Answer (score -1):

Compression does not exists in PostGreSQL. There is no way to do that. The only exception is that LOBs (Large OBjects) are systematically compressed as TOAST which is clearly inappropriate to many LOBs (pictures like .jpg, .png...).

Read my papers about PostGreSQL limitations compare to MS SQL Server.
http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/
particularly § "17 – Data and index compression"

Comment: Thankyou, so compression is not possible in postgresql

Comment: @PriyaChauhan As my and Nikhil's answers suggest, there *is* some degree of compression, but probably in a different way from what you envision. PostgreSQL is pretty wasteful with storage. But then, a relational database is targeted at fast storage and retrieval rather than space-efficient storage.

Comment: @Laurenz_Albe As I show in my reproducible tests, that you can read in my papers, PG is not fast for storage nor for retrieval. Some example shows that PostGreSQL is about 1400 time slower than SQL Server... As an exemple COUNT is the worst of all... http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-2-count-performances/